# Solve "TypeError" in keras (regression problem)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, regression

Here is a part of the *Boston home price prediction* example of the [deep learning with python (Keras)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294438) book.
In this code, I'm iterating over k-folds in order to train the model. But it raises the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-dd5495440c13> in <module>()
     14     axis=0)
     15 
---> 16   model = build_model()
     17   model.fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
     18             epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1, verbose=0)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __init__(self, value)
    212         # int(...) compensates for the int/long dichotomy on Python 2.X.
    213         # TODO(b/143206389): Remove once we fully migrate to 3.X.
--> 214         self._value = int(value.__index__())
    215       except AttributeError:
    216         six.raise_from(

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

in the `model = built_model()` line.
`built_model()` is a function for building a sequential model in order to be used several times.

will you please help me out:(some indentations are ruined)

```
for i in range(k):
  print('processing fold #', i)
  val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
  val_targets = train_targets[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]

  partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
    [train_data[:i * num_val_samples],
    train_data[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],
    axis=0)

  partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
    [train_targets[:i * num_val_samples],
    train_targets[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],
    axis=0)
      
  model = build_model()
  model.fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets,
            epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
  
  val_mse, val_mae = model.evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose=0)
  all_scores.append(val_mae)
```

**and here is the buid_model**

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

def build_model():
  model = models.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data[1],)))
  model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1))
  
  #learning process
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='mse',
                metrics=['mae']
  )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: hi and thanks for your feedback i have edited my question

Comment: Unless you share build_model() function, it is hard to help.

Comment: Yes, the problem clearly happens inside build_model() which you did not share.

Comment: hi, here i added the build_model() function as well. and thanks for your feedback